# Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

Ok so I included the code for my project below, I'm just doing some experimenting with pygame on making a platformer. I'm trying to figure out how to do some very simple scrolling that follows the player, so the player is the center of the camera and it bounces/follows him. Can anyone help me?

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Use arrows to move!")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P       PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "P                                P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        entities.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: instead of moving the player, you move everything else at -playerspeed. It is good, if you have bigger levels, to only blit things that are on the screen.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to say, can you expand a little?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You need to apply an *offset* to the position of your entities when drawing them. Let's call that *offset* a `camera`, since this is the effect we want to achieve with this.

First of all, we can't use the `draw` function of the sprite group, since the sprites don't need to know that their position (`rect`) is not the position they are going to be drawn on the screen (At the end, we'll subclass the `Group` class and reimplement the it's `draw` to be aware of the camera, but let's start slow).

---

Let's start by creating a `Camera` class to hold the state of the offset we want to apply to the position of our entities:

```
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        
    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        
    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
```

some things to note here:

We need to store the position of the camera, and the width and height of the level in pixels (since we want to stop scrolling at the edges of the level). I used a `Rect` to store all these informations, but you could easily just use some fields.

Using `Rect` comes in handy in the `apply` function. This is where we re-calculate the position of an entity on the screen to *apply* the scrolling.

Once per iteration of the main loop, we need to update the position of the camera, hence there's the `update` function. It just alters the state by calling the `camera_func` function, which will do *all the hard work* for us. We implement it later.

Let's create an instace of the camera:

```
for row in level:
    ...

total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32 # calculate size of level in pixels
total_level_height = len(level)*32    # maybe make 32 an constant
camera = Camera(*to_be_implemented*, total_level_width, total_level_height)

entities.add(player)
...
```

and alter our main loop:

```
# draw background
for y in range(32):
    ...

camera.update(player) # camera follows player. Note that we could also follow any other sprite

# update player, draw everything else
player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
for e in entities:
    # apply the offset to each entity.
    # call this for everything that should scroll,
    # which is basically everything other than GUI/HUD/UI
    screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e)) 

pygame.display.update()
```

Our camera class is already very flexible and yet dead simple. It can use different kinds of scrolling (by providing different `camera_func` functions), and it can follow any arbitary sprite, not just the player. You even can change this at runtime.

Now for the implementation of `camera_func`. A simple approach is to just center the player (or whichever entity we want to follow) at the screen, and the implementation is straight forward:

```
def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect # l = left,  t = top
    _, _, w, h = camera      # w = width, h = height
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)
```

We just take the position of our `target`, and add the half total screen size. You can try it by creating your camera like this:

```
camera = Camera(simple_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
```

So far, so good. But maybe we don't want to see the black background *outside* the level? How about:

```
def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    # we want to center target_rect
    x = -target_rect.center[0] + WIN_WIDTH/2 
    y = -target_rect.center[1] + WIN_HEIGHT/2
    # move the camera. Let's use some vectors so we can easily substract/multiply
    camera.topleft += (pygame.Vector2((x, y)) - pygame.Vector2(camera.topleft)) * 0.06 # add some smoothness coolnes
    # set max/min x/y so we don't see stuff outside the world
    camera.x = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), min(0, camera.x))
    camera.y = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), min(0, camera.y))
    
    return camera
```

Here we simply use the `min`/`max` functions to ensure we don't scroll *outside* out level.

Try it by creating your camera like this:

```
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
```

There's a little animation of our final scrolling in action:

[image]

Here's the complete code again. Note I changed some things:

- the level is bigger and to have some more platforms
- use python 3
- use a sprite group to handle the camera
- refactored some duplicate code
- since Vector2/3 is now stable, use them for easier math
- get rid of that ugly event handling code and use `pygame.key.get_pressed` instead

---

```
 #! /usr/bin/python

import pygame
from pygame import *

SCREEN_SIZE = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 800, 640))
TILE_SIZE = 32 
GRAVITY = pygame.Vector2((0, 0.3))

class CameraAwareLayeredUpdates(pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates):
    def __init__(self, target, world_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.cam = pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.world_size = world_size
        if self.target:
            self.add(target)

    def update(self, *args):
        super().update(*args)
        if self.target:
            x = -self.target.rect.center[0] + SCREEN_SIZE.width/2
            y = -self.target.rect.center[1] + SCREEN_SIZE.height/2
            self.cam += (pygame.Vector2((x, y)) - self.cam) * 0.05
            self.cam.x = max(-(self.world_size.width-SCREEN_SIZE.width), min(0, self.cam.x))
            self.cam.y = max(-(self.world_size.height-SCREEN_SIZE.height), min(0, self.cam.y))

    def draw(self, surface):
        spritedict = self.spritedict
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        dirty = self.lostsprites
        self.lostsprites = []
        dirty_append = dirty.append
        init_rect = self._init_rect
        for spr in self.sprites():
            rec = spritedict[spr]
            newrect = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect.move(self.cam))
            if rec is init_rect:
                dirty_append(newrect)
            else:
                if newrect.colliderect(rec):
                    dirty_append(newrect.union(rec))
                else:
                    dirty_append(newrect)
                    dirty_append(rec)
            spritedict[spr] = newrect
        return dirty            
            
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE.size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Use arrows to move!")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

    
    platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(platforms, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    level_width  = len(level[0])*TILE_SIZE
    level_height = len(level)*TILE_SIZE
    entities = CameraAwareLayeredUpdates(player, pygame.Rect(0, 0, level_width, level_height))
    
    # build the level
    x = y = 0
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                Platform((x, y), platforms, entities)
            if col == "E":
                ExitBlock((x, y), platforms, entities)
            x += TILE_SIZE
        y += TILE_SIZE
        x = 0
    
    while 1:

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: 
                return
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        entities.update()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        entities.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        timer.tick(60)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = Surface((TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, platforms, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(Color("#0000FF"), pos)
        self.vel = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))
        self.onGround = False
        self.platforms = platforms
        self.speed = 8
        self.jump_strength = 10
        
    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up = pressed[K_UP]
        left = pressed[K_LEFT]
        right = pressed[K_RIGHT]
        running = pressed[K_SPACE]
        
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.vel.y = -self.jump_strength
        if left:
            self.vel.x = -self.speed
        if right:
            self.vel.x = self.speed
        if running:
            self.vel.x *= 1.5
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.vel += GRAVITY
            # max falling speed
            if self.vel.y > 100: self.vel.y = 100
        print(self.vel.y)
        if not(left or right):
            self.vel.x = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.vel.x
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.vel.x, 0, self.platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.vel.y
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.vel.y, self.platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.vel.y = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(Color("#DDDDDD"), pos, *groups)

class ExitBlock(Entity):
    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(Color("#0033FF"), pos, *groups)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: this is amazing and super informative thank you so much for this answer! And thank you for explaining everything clearly, I was really able to read this and understand everything you did and why you did it!

Comment: The kind of reply that has earned a home delivery of pies.

Comment: Here are the 4 part video tutorials for the above. Detailed explanation.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpufbRZxKRM

Comment: I realize this is ancient at this point, but still works wonderfully.  I think you have a typo in the `ExitBlock` class ... shouldn't it inherit from Entity instead of Platform?  (if you add an `E` to the map you get a TypeError otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Pygame doesn't have a built-in solution to this problem. Pygame use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects organized in [`pygame.sprite.Group`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). The attribute `.rect` of the *Sprites* is used for drawing the objects as well as for the collision test between objects. There is no built-in feature that can convert object coordinates to screen coordinates before drawing.
As a suggestion for the developers of Pygame: It would be nice to have an optional argument for the camera *offset* in the method [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw).

There a different approaches:

- Instead of moving the player, you can move any object in the scene in the opposite direction. This is the worst of all approaches. I strongly recommend not doing this.
  Every time you add a new object you need to make sure that it moves as the player moves. Dealing with object animation or floating point accuracy can turn out to be a nightmare.
- Create a virtual screen size of the world and draw the entire screen on the virtual screen. At the end of each frame, a subsection of the map is displayed on the screen.

  ```py
  virtual_screen = pygame.Surface((map_width, map_height))
  ```

  There are 2 possibilities. You can [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) an area of the virtual screen directly on the screen by specifying the *area* argument:

  ```py
  camera_area = pygame.Rect(camera_x, camera_y, camera_width, camera_height)
  screen.blit(virtual_screen, (0, 0), camera_area)
  ```

  The other possibility is to define a subsurface that is linked directly to the source surface using the[`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) method:

  ```py
  camera_area = pygame.Rect(camera_x, camera_y, camera_width, camera_height)
  camera_subsurf = source_surf.subsurface(camera_area)
  ```

  ```py
  screen.blit(camera_subsurf, (0, 0))
  ```

  The disadvantage of this approach is that it can have a very large memory footprint. If the virtual screen is huge, the game will lag. This solution is only suitable if the size of the game area is not much larger than the screen. As a rule of thumb, if the play area is more than twice the size of the screen, you shouldn't go this way (I'm talking about twice the size of the area, not twice the length of its width and height).
- For large play areas, the only approach that can be used is to add an offset to the objects before drawing:

  ```py
  offset_x = -camera_x
  offset_y = -camera_y
  for object in objects:
      screen.blit(object.image, (object.rect.x + offset_x, object.rect.y + offset_y))
  ```

  Unfortunately [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) can not be used directly in this case. This approach is detailed in a highly rated answer.
  Alternatively, you can move all of the sprites before drawing them:

  ```py
  all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
  ```

  ```py
  for sprite in all_sprites:
      all_sprites.rect.move_ip(-camera_x, -camera_y)
  all_sprites.draw(screen)    
  for sprite in all_sprites:
      all_sprites.rect.move_ip(camera_x, camera_y)
  ```

At the end a comment about dirty mechanisms and partial screen updates: As soon as the player moves, the entire screen is dirty and needs to be updated. It is therefore questionable whether you should invest resources in partial update mechanisms. These algorithms also take time to run. In highly dynamic scenes, the result of the algorithm is to update all.

Answer (score 0):

Since right know, you have a static background, and the player that you control, is blitted in the position he is in, you have 2 options to always show the character in the middle.

1. If you map is small enought, you can have a big img A, and derive a rectangle, based on the position of the player that will be the size of the screen. That way, the player will always be in the middle. A Rect.clamp(Rect) or Rect.clamp_ip(Rect) will aid you in that.
2. Another approach is to have a different tuple for position on screen. The player will have a constant value in the center of the screen, while the backgrounds position will be the negative of the player position.

Comment: Ok well since the maps usually won't be small in the final design I think option 2 would be better. How would I implement this? I'm mainly confused where the offsets or screen changes would be applied

Comment: since you are using the built in sprite of pygame, there isn't a straightforward way to do this. You can override the draw function, in those sprites, to blit the image in a different place. You can derive the position of the surrond objects by (the position of the object - player_pos)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to separate logical positions in the map, from physical positions on the screen .

Any code related to actually drawing your map on the screen - in your case all the `.rect` attributes of your sprites - have to do so based on an offset of  what part of yor map the screen is actually using.

For example, your screen might be showing your map starting with position (10,10) on the top left - all display related code them (which in the case above are the `.rect`attributes)  should subtract the screen offset from the current logical position - (say the character is at map coords(12,15) - so, it should be drawn at (12,15) - (10, 10) -> (2, 5) * BLOCK_SIZE) 
In your example above BLOCK_SIZE is hardcoded to 32,32, so you want to draw it at physical pixel position (2 * 32, 5 * 32) on the display)

(hint: avoid hardcoding things this way, make it a constant declaration at the beginning of your code)