# Getting World Coordinates with mouse in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble updating the mouse position and checking for entity collisions (between the mouse and entity) due to my level scrolling. I have used the camera function from this question: [How to add scrolling to platformer in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/how-to-add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame)

I have tried to use the camera function on the mouse like this:

```
def update(self, target, target_type, mouse):
        if target_type != "mouse":
            self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
        else:
            new_pos = self.camera_func(mouse.rect, target.rect)
            mouse.update((new_pos[0], new_pos[1]))
            print mouse.rect
```

but the mouse.rect is consistently set to `608, 0`. Can someone help me with this? The mouse class looks like this:

```
class Mouse(Entity):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.rect = Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 32, 32)

    def update(self, pos, check=False):
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.rect.top = pos[1]
        self.rect.left = pos[0]

        if check:
            print "Mouse Pos: %s" %(self.rect)
            print self.x, self.y
```

Everytime I click the screen, and pass it through a collision test, it always uses the point on the screen, however I need the point on the map (if that makes sense). For example, the screen size is `640x640`. If I click in the top left corner, the mouse position will always be `0,0` however, the actual map coordinates may `320,180` in the top corner of the screen. I have attempted to update everything with the camera and the mouse, and the only real results are when I apply the `camera.update` function to the mouse, but this stop the player being the cause of the scrolling, so I therefore attempted to update the `mouse.rect` with this function.

Attempted code:

```
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_offset = camera.apply(mouse)
    pos = mouse_pos[0] + mouse_offset.left, mouse_pos[1] + mouse_offset.top
    mouse.update(mouse_pos)
    if hit_block:
        print "Mouse Screen Pos: ", mouse_pos
        print "Mouse Pos With Offset: ", pos
        print "Mouse Offset: ", mouse_offset
        replace_block(pos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera calculates the screen coordinate by a given world coordinate.

Since the mouse position is already a screen coordinate, if you want to get the tile under the mouse, you have to *substract* the offset, *not add* it.

You can add the following method to the `Camera` class:

```
def reverse(self, pos):
    """Gets the world coordinates by screen coordinates"""
    return (pos[0] - self.state.left, pos[1] - self.state.top)
```

and use it like this:

```
    mouse_pos = camera.reverse(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    if hit_block:
        replace_block(mouse_pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you read the mouse that's *screen coordinates*. Since you're scrolling, you need *world coordinates* to check the collisions.

Your render loop simplifies to

```
# draw: x+offset
for e in self.entities:
    screen.draw(e.sprite, e.rect.move(offset))
```

which is the same as `draw( world_to_screen( e.rect ))`

Your click would be `collidepoint( screen_to_world( pos ))`

```
# mouseclick
pos = event.pos[0] + offset.left, event.pos[1] + offset.top
for e in self.entities:
    if e.collidepoint(pos):
        print("click:", pos)
```

Comment: I added my code to the actual answer and there seems to be an issue where the offset begins decreasing as it goes past the screen height or width

Comment: If you paste your full code to pastebin (So I can run it) I can take a look.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Instead of just posting the code, maybe you want to check-in the code into a public repository (on GitHub/BitBucket/etc.) with images included, so it would be easy for others to just check-out and run your code. If you don't use source control, better start using it now.

Comment: I meant to add the link, but must have got caught up :/ my bad :/