# Mapping coordinates to screen in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, chunks

Ok, lots of explaining to follow, so bear with me.

I'm making a 2D top-down game in PyGame, and I have a "chunk loading" system set up. The system is as follows...

I have a "world" object, made up of "chunks". Each chunk is 16x16 "tiles" and contains data for each one of those tiles. In the world object, I have a system for generating these chunks as needs be, and storing them in a dictionary, like `{(x, y):"grass"} etc...` Each tile in the chunk is a 10px image, that needs to be drawn to the screen in PyGame, given the position of the camera (*counted in tiles*). I want the camera to be able to pan around over the top of these images, and move around. How on earth can I make this work?

A quick diagram...

[diagram http://williamgardner.noip.me/files/chunks](http://williamgardner.noip.me/files/chunks)

I hope this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, TomTsagk explained it really good:

[Pygame camera follow in a 2d tile game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746552/pygame-camera-follow-in-a-2d-tile-game)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want, but I think I can adapt it slightly, thanks!