# How to make a scrolling screen in python with a simple camera class

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to make a game in python where the screen needs to scroll with the player character.  I learned some strange methods of doing things in python and have no knowledge of how blitting works.  My teacher didn't show us much more than what appears in the code I am enclosing below.  I want the screen to move so that the Rizer class is always in the center of the screen.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
#Contra 5
import pygame
import math, random, time
from livewires import games, color
games.init(screen_width = 1000, screen_height = 480, fps = 100)
#Add things to stand on as opposed to only standing on the y value of
#250, thus creating the illusion of a solid object.
#Make it so you can't hold down the jump button to stay in the air.
#Make lives.
#Make it so you don't die when crouching and shooting.
#Put in a Camera for the purpose of a scrolling screen.
#Put in a way for 2 players to play at once, be able to shoot, and have their
#bullets not doing damage to teammates.
#Make it so the title screen works.
##ONLY ADD MORE STAGES AND MUSIC ONCE THE FIRST STAGE AND TITLE SCREEN IS DONE.##
class Wrapper(games.Sprite):
    """ A sprite that wraps around the screen. """
    def update(self):
        """ Wrap sprite around screen. """    
        if self.top > games.screen.height:
            self.bottom = self.bottom

        if self.bottom < 0:
            self.top = self.top

        if self.left > games.screen.width:
            self.right = self.right

        if self.right < 0:
            self.left = self.left

    def die(self):
        """ Destroy self. """
        self.destroy()
class Collider(Wrapper):
    """ A Wrapper that can collide with another object. """
    def update(self):
        """ Check for overlapping sprites. """
        super(Collider, self).update()

        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            for sprite in self.overlapping_sprites:
                sprite.die()
            self.die()

    def die(self):
        """ Destroy self """
        self.destroy()
class Rizer(Collider):
    #Player One
    #make it so your own bullets cannot kill you at all.
    image = games.load_image("rizer.bmp")
    image2 = games.load_image("rizerl.bmp")
    image4 = games.load_image("rizerupr.bmp")
    image5 = games.load_image("rizerupl.bmp")
    image6 = games.load_image("rizercrouchr.bmp")
    image7 = games.load_image("rizercrouchl.bmp")
    image8 = games.load_image("rizerjump1.bmp")
    image9 = games.load_image("rizerjump2.bmp")
    image10 = games.load_image("rizerjump3.bmp")
    image11 = games.load_image("rizerjump4.bmp")
    direction = 0
    jumpnumber = 0
    crouch = 0
    up = 0
    lives = 3
    shot = 0
    BULLET_DELAY = 50
    VELOCITY_FACTOR = 3
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image,
                                  x = 200,
                                  bottom = 250)
        self.bullet_wait = 0
    def update(self):
        super(Rizer, self).update()
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_a):
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image2,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)
            self.x = self.x - 2
            Rizer.direction = 1
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_d):
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom) 
            self.x = self.x + 2
            Rizer.direction = 0

        if self.bullet_wait > 0:
            self.bullet_wait -= 1
        if self.bottom == 250 and Rizer.direction == 1:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image2,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
        if self.bottom == 250 and Rizer.direction == 0:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
        if self.bottom > 250:
            self.bottom = 250    

        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_j) and self.bullet_wait == 0:
            self.bullet_wait = Rizer.BULLET_DELAY
            new_bullet = Bullet(self.x, self.y)
            games.screen.add(new_bullet)
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_w) and Rizer.direction == 0:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image4,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            up = 1
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_w) and Rizer.direction == 1:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image5,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            up = 2            
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_s) and Rizer.direction == 0:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image6,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            crouch = 2
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_s) and Rizer.direction == 1:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image7,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            crouch = 1
        #Jumping Portion with animation
        #Jump Timer
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        FPS, timer = 60,0
        flag = False
        #The actual jump portion
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_k):
            flag = True
            timer = 1 * FPS
            self.y = self.y - 2
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image8,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image9,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image10,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image11,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)
        #Make it so that you come back down after 1 second of jumping.
        if timer:
            timer -= 1
        else:
            flag = False
            self.y = self.y + 2
        #Make sure you can't jump too high
        if self.y < 100:
            self.y = 100
        if self.x < 35:
            self.x = 35
        #Kill self if Rizer touches another object.
        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.destroy()
        #Return the sprite to standing form after a jump
        if self.bottom < 250:
            super(Rizer, self).__init__(image = Rizer.image11,
                                        x = self.x,
                                        bottom = self.bottom)


class Bean(Collider):
    #Player Two
    image = games.load_image("bean.bmp")
    image2 = games.load_image("beanl.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bean, self).__init__(image = Bean.image,
                                  x = 2000,
                                  bottom = 250)    
    def update(self):
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_LEFT):
            super(Bean, self).__init__(image = Bean.image2,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)
            self.x = self.x - 2
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_RIGHT):
            super(Bean, self).__init__(image = Bean.image,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom) 
            self.x = self.x + 2
class Runner(Collider):
    image = games.load_image("runner.bmp")
    lives = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(Runner, self).__init__(image = Runner.image,
                                     x = 600, bottom = 250)
    def update(self):
        self.x = self.x - 1
class Shooter(Collider):
    An enemy with a gun
    image = games.load_image("shooter.bmp")
    lives = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(Shooter, self).__init__(image = Shooter.image,
                                     x = 800, bottom = 250)
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_r):
            new_ebullet = EBullet(Shooter.x, Shooter.y)
            games.screen.add(new_ebullet)
    def update(self):
        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.destroy()
class EBullet(Collider):
    #The bullet that the enemy shoots
    image = games.load_image("ebullet.bmp")
    sound = games.load_sound("shot.ogg")
    BUFFER = 100
    VELOCITY_FACTOR = 7
    LIFETIME = 60
    lives = 0

    def __init__(self, shooter_x, shooter_y,):
        """ Initialize missile sprite. """
        Bullet.sound.play()
        x = 730
        y = 270
        dx = -self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
        dy = 0
        super(EBullet, self).__init__(image = EBullet.image,
                                      x = x, y = y,
                                      dx = dx, dy = dy)
        self.lifetime = Bullet.LIFETIME






class Spreadp(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("spower.bmp")
    shot = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(Spreadp, self).__init__(image = Spreadp.image,
                                     x = 680, bottom = 240)
        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            shot = 1
            self.destroy()

class Rizerlives(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("rizerlife.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rizerlives, self).__init__(image = Rizerlives.image,
                                     x = 10, bottom = 25)
class Rizerlivesa(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("rizerlife.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rizerlivesa, self).__init__(image = Rizerlivesa.image,
                                     x = 25, bottom = 25)


class Bullet(Collider):
    """ A bullet launched by a player character. """
    image = games.load_image("bullet.bmp")
    image2 = games.load_image("spreader.bmp")
    image3 = games.load_image("explosion1.bmp")
    sound = games.load_sound("shot.ogg")
    BUFFER = 100
    VELOCITY_FACTOR = 10
    LIFETIME = 60
    lives = 0

    def __init__(self, rizer_x, rizer_y,):
        """ Initialize missile sprite. """
        Bullet.sound.play()

        # calculate missile's starting position
        if Rizer.direction == 0 and Rizer.crouch == 0 and Rizer.up == 0:
            x = rizer_x + 60
            y = rizer_y - 20
            dx = self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
            dy = 0
        if Rizer.direction == 1 and Rizer.crouch == 0 and Rizer.up == 0:
            x = rizer_x - 60
            y = rizer_y - 20
            dx = -self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
            dy = 0
        if Rizer.crouch == 2 and Rizer.up == 0:
            x = rizer_x + 120
            y = rizer_y + 40
            dx = self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
            dy = 0
        if Rizer.crouch == 1 and Rizer.up == 0:
            x = rizer_x - 120
            y = rizer_y + 40
            dx = -self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
            dy = 0
        if Rizer.up == 1 or Rizer.up == 2:
            x = rizer_x
            y = rizer_y - 60
            dx = 0
            dy = -self.VELOCITY_FACTOR
        if Spreadp.shot == 0:
            super(Bullet, self).__init__(image = Bullet.image,
                                          x = x, y = y,
                                          dx = dx, dy = dy)
        if Spreadp.shot == 1:
            super(Bullet, self).__init__(image = Bullet.image2,
                                          x = x, y = y,
                                          dx = dx, dy = dy)
        if Spreadp.shot == 2:
            super(Bullet, self).__init__(image = Bullet.image3,
                                         x = x, y = y,
                                         dx = dx, dy = dy)
        self.lifetime = Bullet.LIFETIME

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
        super(Bullet, self).update()
        # if lifetime is up, destroy the bullet
        self.lifetime -= 1
        if self.lifetime == 0:
            self.destroy()    
class Cursor(games.Sprite):
    cursorspot = 1
    image = games.load_image("cursor.bmp",transparent = False)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cursor, self).__init__(image = Cursor.image,
                                  x = 210,
                                  bottom = 345)
    def update(self):
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_1):
            self.y = 335
            cursorspot = 1
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_2):
            self.y = 365
            cursorspot = 2
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_SPACE):
            self.destroy()
def main():
    #title = games.load_image("contratitle.bmp",transparent = False)
    #games.screen.background = title
    #cursor = Cursor()
    #games.screen.add(cursor)       
    screen = games.load_image("jungle.bmp", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = screen
    file2 = 'contra.mp3'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file2)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    rizer = Rizer()
    games.screen.add(rizer)
    runner = Runner()
    games.screen.add(runner)
    shooter = Shooter()
    games.screen.add(shooter)
    spreadpower = Spreadp()
    #games.screen.add(spreadpower)
    rizerlives = Rizerlives()
    games.screen.add(rizerlives)
    rizerlivesa = Rizerlivesa()
    games.screen.add(rizerlivesa)
    #bean = Bean()
    #games.screen.add(bean)
    games.screen.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not programming the same way.  For example, the screen settings are set up differently.

Answer (score 0):

Create lists that contain different groups of sprites, I.e: allSpriteList, allButPlayerList...

Then you can have a similar method in the classes that represent all objects that aren't the player and call them iteratively.

```
for sprite in allSpritesExceptPlayer:
    Sprite.move_left()
```

Let me know if you need specifics. Pygame has a helpful Group class that is worth looking into.