# Choosing which sound to play in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In Pygame how would I define which sound I want to play in certain "if" events? I've been able to load them both in I just hit the issue of not playing either on demand. Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? Just make an if statement and set your sound to play nested within.

Comment: I have currently got two if statements but when I try to use Pygame.mixer.music.play(1)  it just takes the first song from the song list I made.

Comment: You have to use a sound object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a sound object to play sounds.

```
if condition_one_true:
    sound_one = Sound('sound1.mp3')
    sound_one.play()

if condition_two_true:
    sound_two= Sound('sound2.mp3')
    sound_two.play()
```