# Pygame collision handling

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, collision

I made a 2D platformer game with pygame. I am struggling to figure out how to determine the direction an object is moving in.

For example: say the player is coming from above since his y velocity is greater than zero, then the problems are that his gravitation is acting on him constantly; this means that if he comes from the left side, his y velocity is greater than zero (so this if statement will get triggered even though I want the left-side-if statement to get triggered).

The source code for this is the following: `

```
if self.hits:
    for platform in self.hits:

        if self.player.vel.y > 0:
            self.player.rect.y = platform.rect.top
            self.player.vel.y = 0

        if self.player.vel.y < 0:
            self.player.rect.top = platform.rect.bottom
            self.player.vel.y = 0

        if self.player.vel.x > 0:
            self.player.rect.right = platform.rect.left

        if self.player.vel.y < 0:
            self.player.rect.left = platform.rect.right
```

That is why I created some limitations for the recognition of each four directions: `

```
if self.hits:
   for platform in self.hits:

       if self.player.rect.bottom >= (platform.rect.top) and self.player.rect.bottom <= (platform.rect.top + 16)\
       and (self.player.rect.centerx + 13) >= platform.rect.left and (self.player.rect.centerx - 13) <= platform.rect.right:
               self.player.pos_bottom.y = platform.rect.top
               self.player.vel.y = 0

       elif self.player.rect.top <= (platform.rect.bottom) and self.player.rect.top >= (platform.rect.bottom - 16)\
       and (self.player.rect.centerx + 13) >= platform.rect.left and (self.player.rect.centerx - 13) <= platform.rect.right:
               self.player.rect.top = platform.rect.bottom
               self.player.vel.y = 0

       elif self.player.rect.right >= (platform.rect.left) and self.player.rect.right <= (platform.rect.right + 10) and self.player.vel.x >= 0\
       and self.player.rect.centery >= platform.rect.top and self.player.rect.centery <= platform.rect.bottom:
           self.player.rect.right = platform.rect.left
           self.player.vel.x = 0

       elif self.player.rect.left <= (platform.rect.right) and self.player.rect.left >= (platform.rect.right - 10) and self.player.vel.x <= 0\
       and self.player.rect.centery >= platform.rect.top and self.player.rect.centery <= platform.rect.bottom:
           self.player.rect.left = platform.rect.right
           self.player.vel.x = 0`
```

This code limitates the zone in which the players direction is getting recognized, but brings a lot of bugs with it and is also really ugly.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354171/142637) question/answer. See how the collision detection is done in two steps: first for the x axis, then the y axis. This works quite well.

Comment: thank you that really helped me