# Moving a Tiled map in pygame according to the players movement

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to be able to move the map and character of a 2D game i'm making i make the tiles by doing this:

```
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x*32,y*32,32,32), 2)
```

and to move the map i do y += 32 but this doesn't work and the map just stays the same way. So how would i get the map to move using the code above! My question is different to the tagged question as i just want to simply move the map when the player presses W,A,S or D using the above code! I have tried to dd the tile width and height which is 32 pixels to the x and y integers but some box's weren't appearing.

Here's My full Code:
Main.py

```
import pygame, math
from scripts.Engine import *

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)


pygame.init()

size = (600,600)
width = size[0]
height = size[1]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size), pygame.RESIZABLE)
face = "North"

playerN = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Uplayer.png")
playerS = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Dplayer.png")
playerE = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Rplayer.png")
playerW = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Lplayer.png")


grass = pygame.image.load("Tiles\\grass.png")

camera_x = 0
camera_y = 0
TileSize = 32
player_w, player_h = 40, 52
player_x = (width / 2 - player_w / 2 - camera_x) / TileSize
player_y = (height / 2 - player_h / 2 - camera_y) / TileSize

while True:
    screen.fill(blue)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    Engine.Map(screen, 20, 20, grass, 32)
    move = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if move[pygame.K_w]:
        face = "North"
        camera_y -= 32 # Move map This doesnt work
        player_y -= 10 # Move Sprite around map This works
    elif move[pygame.K_s]:
        camera_y += 32
        player_y += 10
        face = "South"
    elif move[pygame.K_a]:
        face = "West"
        camera_x -= 32
        player_x -= 10
    elif move[pygame.K_d]:
        face = "East"
        camera_x += 32
        player_x += 10


    if face == "North":
        screen.blit(playerN, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "South":
        screen.blit(playerS, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "East":
        screen.blit(playerE, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "West":
        screen.blit(playerW, (player_x, player_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Game Engine: Tiles made here

```
import pygame

class Engine:

    def Map(surface, w, h, tileType,TileSize):
        global x,y
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                surface.blit(tileType, (x*TileSize,y*TileSize))
```

This is my full code so far i can move the player but not the tiles themselves I don't know why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame)

Comment: Seems a bit complex for something i am trying to achieve. I just want to move the grid when the player hits a keys such as w

Comment: It may seem complex, but the concepts are sound. But without more code (post a minimal runnable piece of code) it will be hard to figure out what is going on with yours. We need to see your map variable at least and how you are adjusting it

Comment: added full code the sprite itself moves but the tiles don't. It would be great if you told me why it isn't working and how to fix it

Comment: do you wan the player to move around a stationary map? or the map to move around a stationary player?

Comment: you also update `camera` but never do anything with it. the call to `Engine.Map(screen, 20, 20, grass, 32)' never changes

Comment: So do i use camera as one of the arguments and add it in with the map engine so when it loads the map it also uses camera positions. Is that the problem

Comment: I want the player to move with the map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185227/discussion-between-dextron-and-the4thiceman).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but when i move up or left the map keeps generating after the map amount currently the map amount is 40 but it will keep creating tiles. But when i go down or right it shows the blue screen behind the tiles when i get to the last tile. Ill post another question on how to fix it.

Main.py:

```
import pygame, math
from scripts.Engine import *

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)

pygame.init()

size = (600,600)
width = size[0]
height = size[1]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size), pygame.RESIZABLE)
face = "North"

playerN = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Uplayer.png")
playerS = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Dplayer.png")
playerE = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Rplayer.png")
playerW = pygame.image.load("Sprites\\Lplayer.png")


grass = pygame.image.load("Tiles\\grass.png")

TileSize = 32
player_w, player_h = 40, 52
player_x = (width / 2 - player_w / 2 - camera_x) / TileSize
player_y = (height / 2 - player_h / 2 - camera_y) / TileSize

mapW = camera_x
mapH = camera_y

while True:
    print(camera_x, camera_y)
    screen.fill(blue)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    Engine.Map(screen, camera_x, camera_y, grass, 32, camera_x, camera_y)
    move = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if move[pygame.K_w]:
        if camera_x > mapH:
            pass
        else:
            face = "North"
            camera_y += 1 # Move map This doesnt work
    elif move[pygame.K_s]:
        camera_y -= 1
        face = "South"
    elif move[pygame.K_a]:
        face = "West"
        if camera_x > mapW:
            pass
        else:
            camera_x += 1
    elif move[pygame.K_d]:
        face = "East"
        camera_x -= 1
        #player_x += 10


    if face == "North":
        screen.blit(playerN, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "South":
        screen.blit(playerS, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "East":
        screen.blit(playerE, (player_x, player_y))
    elif face == "West":
        screen.blit(playerW, (player_x, player_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Game Engine.py:

```
import pygame

class Engine:

    def Map(surface, w, h, tileType,TileSize, camera_x, camera_y):
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                surface.blit(tileType, (x*TileSize,y*TileSize))
```

Comment: To stop the map constantly generating, you take the engine out of the loop and draw the rectangles or tiles to another surface then display the surface in the loop but don't refresh the surface