# Adding a vertical and horizontal scroll bar to the display surface in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame and I've been working so far in a large monitor, but now I need to work on a small laptop, whose screen is much smaller than the mentioned monitor. The dimensions I gave to the display surface and the items blitted to it work well on the previous monitor but it is too large on the laptop and therefore I cannot reach all buttons. Since I can't seem to find a way to resize everything proportionaly, is there an easy way to add a vertical and horizontal scroll bar in order to navigate around the display surface?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't an easy way to implement scrolling as you have to implement it all by your self (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357169/6486738). Scaling proportionally is also something you have to do by yourself, but that is a bit easier if listen to the resize event, and scale all your surfaces with `pygame.transform.scale` with some proportion relative to the new screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can add a scroll bar. What you can do is shift the x or y of everything when you press the corresponding arrow keys. But as said by Ted Klein Bergman, it is better to simply resize everything.