# How to create a "Solid" block? pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to implement solid blocks to my simple platformer game I´m working on, but I don´t know how.
I tried lots of things, but nothing work.
I want to do following:
when I jUMP on it, I will stay there
when I jump underneath it, I won´t reach the top
when I jump from left side, I won´t reach the right side
when I jump from right side, I won´t reach the left side

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

my code:

````
from pygame.locals import *
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1923
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load('C:\Sprites\mrkva.png').convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 9

    def update(self, pressed_keys):

        if pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-10, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(10, 0)

        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-10, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(10, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= 970:
            self.rect.bottom = 970
    
    def jump(self):
        if self.isJump:
            if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 3
                if self.jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -3
                self.rect.y -= self.jumpCount**2 * 0.101 * neg
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.isJump = False
                self.jumpCount = 9

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xloc, yloc):
        super(Platform, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load('C:\Sprites\kocka.png').convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = yloc
        self.rect.x = xloc

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption('gameee')
platform = Platform(1, 527)
player = Player(1, 969)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(platform)
all_sprites.add(player)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                player.isJump = True

        elif event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

    clock.tick(35)
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
    screen.fill((28, 173, 234))
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.jump()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: The best pygame platform example on Stack Overflow is [Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame).

Comment: thanks Rabbid, but I´m not sure if this is the same problem i´m struggling with

Comment: I´m not going to copy someone´s else code

Comment: I´m not arguing and I´m sorry if it sounds like I am.
Yeah, I´ll copy someone´s answer, but It´ll be only few lines, not full code

Comment: @sloth I´m not sure if I understood you well, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing a collision test in platformer, you must always consider the direction of movement of the player. The player's reaction is different as they hit a platform from above or below. This can lead to different cases in your code.

I'll give you an example of how to land on a platform, based on your code.

---

First, correct the code that makes the player jump. Add a constant for the jump count and round the player's y coordinate. So the player falls on the same distance as it moves up:

```py
JUMP_COUNT = 10

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # [...]

        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = JUMP_COUNT

    # [...]
    
    def jump(self):
        if self.isJump:
            if self.jumpCount >= -JUMP_COUNT:
                neg = 3
                if self.jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -3
                self.rect.y -= round(self.jumpCount**2 * 0.101 * neg)
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.isJump = False
                self.jumpCount = JUMP_COUNT
```

Save the player's y coordinate before moving the player. Check for collisions after the player moves. If the player falls and a collision is detected, place the bottom of the player on top of the platform:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    prev_y = player.rect.y
    
    player.jump()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    if player.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
        dir_y = player.rect.y - prev_y
        if dir_y > 0:
            player.isJump = False
            player.jumpCount = JUMP_COUNT
            player.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top

    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

Comment: okey, thanks for help, I read it and I tried to understand it, but it doesn´t work.
when I jump **for first time** it will teleport me above

Comment: @Meel The GIF is created from your code using my suggestions. I've just changed the screen size and position of the player and platform, and I'm using uniform colored surfaces.

Comment: That´s weird...
I found that the problem is in the your last section
this:
`if player.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
        dir_y = player.rect.y - prev_y
        if dir_y > 0:
            player.isJump = False
            player.jumpCount = JUMP_COUNT
            player.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top`

beacuse when I remove this part, it works

Comment: @Meel Sorry, that can't be the case. There is another bug in your code. However, I cannot see your code or debug it.

Comment: As you said, there was another bug, and I found it. now it works correctly.
Please, excuse my previous behavior...:/

Comment: @Meel Never mind. I do not have a problem. And I think I didn't get you right. My native language is not English and I have trouble understanding the fine details.

Comment: Thanks, by the way my native language is also not English, so for me, it wasn't easy too (and my phrasing is sometimes very awful)