# How do I add a camera with a sprite grid in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

**I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame), and am still trying to add this answer. This IS NOT a duplicate.**

I have a 20x20 grid, and the screen size is 800x640. The screen cannot see the full grid, and I want it to be able to via a scrolling camera.

However, I am not sure how I would even implement this.

The way my code works is that, in the main loop, `player.update()` is called to update the player's position and collision, and then an `update()` function is called, which redraws all sprites in the grid (to show any changes).

Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import random
import time
pygame.init()
W, Height = 800, 640

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W,Height))

SCREEN_SIZE = pygame.Rect((0,0,W,Height))
TILE_SIZE = 48

t0 = time.time()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
print("Time needed to create fonts: " + str(time.time() - t0))

vec = pygame.math.Vector2

# USER CAN MODIFY
ACC = 0.5
FRIC = -0.12
FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class BlueBlock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    super(BlueBlock, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.Surface((48,48))
    self.surf.fill((0,191,255))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.original_surface = self.surf
    self.hover_surface = self.original_surface.copy()
    pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_surface, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_surface.get_rect(), 6)
    self.surf = self.original_surface
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    self.hover = False
    self.mouse_pos = None
    self.count = 0
    
  def update(self):
    if player.mode == "build":
      mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
      self.surf = self.hover_surface if self.hover else self.original_surface
      if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos:
        self.count += 1
      if self.count > 10:
        self.image = pygame.Surface((48,48))
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))

class textureblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, imagefile, x, y, type):
    super(textureblock, self).__init__()
      
    self.imagefile = imagefile
    self.original_image = pygame.image.load(imagefile).convert_alpha()
    self.original_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (48,48))
    self.hover_image = self.original_image.copy()
    pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    self.image = self.original_image 
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    self.hover = False
    self.mouse_pos = None
    self.count = 0
    self.type = type

  def update(self):
    if player.mode == "build":
      pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255,0,0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    elif player.mode == "destroy":
      pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255, 255,0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    self.image = self.hover_image if self.hover else self.original_image
    if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos and player.mode == "destroy":
      self.count += 1
      if self.count > 10:
        self.image = pygame.Surface((48,48))
        self.image.fill((0,191,255))

        item = Item(self.imagefile, self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.type)
        
        items.add(item)
        self.remove(blocks)
      
    else:
      self.count = 0
    self.mouse_pos = mouse_pos
  
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Player, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.Surface((40,40))
    self.surf.fill((255,0,0))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.pos = vec(0,144) # Position
    self.vel = vec(0,0) # Velocity
    self.acc = vec(0,0) # Acceleration 
    self.inventory = {} # Items can be added
    self.mode = "destroy" # Mode. Probably will be changed later
    self.selected_item = None # Selected item

  def move(self, pressed_keys):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
      self.acc.x = -ACC
      
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
      self.acc.x = ACC
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0

  def update(self):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
      self.acc.x = -ACC
      
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
      self.acc.x = ACC
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

    self.pos.y += self.vel.y + 0.5 * self.acc.y
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = entity.rect.top
                self.pos.y = self.rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
    if self.vel.y > 0:
      if hits: 
        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        self.vel.y = 0

  def jump(self):
    self.vel.y = -15

# Item class - Spawned when a player breaks a block.
class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, image, x, y, type):
    super(Item, self).__init__()
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (24,24))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
    self.pos = vec(x, y)
    self.vel = vec(0,0)
    self.acc = vec(0,0)
    self.type = type

  def move(self):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0

  def update(self):
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

    self.pos.y += self.vel.y + 0.5 * self.acc.y
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = entity.rect.top
                self.pos.y = self.rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
    if self.vel.y > 0:
      if hits: 
        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        self.vel.y = 0

    # Now we check if we hit the Player
    if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
      # Attempt to check the player inventory
      if self.type not in player.inventory.keys():
        
        player.inventory[self.type] = 1
        self.kill()
      else:
        
        player.inventory.update({self.type: player.inventory.get(self.type) + 1})
        self.kill()
       
player = Player()
blueblock = BlueBlock(0,0)

running = True

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
items = pygame.sprite.Group()
miscBlocks = pygame.sprite.Group()

def drawGraph(graph, start):
  y = start
  x = 0
  for item in graph:
    if item == "O":
      spr = BlueBlock(x, y)
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      miscBlocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.surf, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "G":
      spr = textureblock("media/Grass.jpeg", x, y, "Grass")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
      
    elif item == "S":
      spr = textureblock("media/Stone.png",x,y, "Stone")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "C":
      spr = textureblock("media/Coal.jpeg",x,y, "Coal")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "NL":
      y += 48
      x = 0
    else:
      print("Item not found: " + item)
  print("[Debug] Generation finished. Amount of blocks: " + str(len(blocks.sprites())))

def randomGen(graph):
  print("[Debug] Begin randomGen...")
  # We assume the user has not done anything with the graph, so we add the sky and grass
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('G')
  newgraph.append('NL')

  # Next begins the random ore gen
  
  for i in range(20):
    x = 0
    for i in range(20):
      # Chance of coal - 1 in 15
      iscoal = random.randint(1,15)
      
      if iscoal == 6:
        graph.append("C")
       
      else:
        graph.append("S")
      x += 48
    graph.append('NL')
  print("[Debug] randomGen finished. Block Stats: %s air blocks, %s grass blocks, %s stone blocks, %s coal blocks, and %s newlines." % (str(graph.count('O')), str(graph.count('G')), str(graph.count('S')), str(graph.count('C')), str(graph.count('NL'))))

newgraph = []
randomGen(newgraph)

all_sprites.add(player)

def update():
  for entity in all_sprites:
    try:
      screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    except:
      screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
  screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
  for entity in blocks:
    screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
  for entity in items:
    screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
  pygame.display.update()

drawGraph(newgraph, 0)

# Calculate the size of the level
level_width = 0
for i in newgraph:
  if i != "NL":
    level_width += 1
  elif i == "NL":
    break
level_width = level_width * TILE_SIZE

level_height = (newgraph.count("NL")-1)*TILE_SIZE

print("[Debug] Calculated level width and height: %s and %s" % (str(level_width), str(level_height)))

while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        player.jump()
      if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
      if event.key == pygame.K_e:
        if len(player.inventory) == 0:
          print("Player Inventory: Empty")
        else:
          print("Player Inventory: " + str(player.inventory).replace("{", "").replace("}","").replace(":", " x").replace("'",""))
      if event.key == pygame.K_b:
        if player.mode == "build":
          player.mode = "destroy"
        elif player.mode == "destroy":
          player.mode = "build"
        print("Changed player mode to " + player.mode)
      if event.key == pygame.K_1:
        
        player.selected_item = list(player.inventory)[0]
        print("Item: " + list(player.inventory)[0])
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      x,y = event.pos
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
      pygame.quit()
      
  miscBlocks.update()
  blocks.update()
  blocks.draw(screen)
  
  pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  for entity in items:
    entity.move()
  # Commented out because it lagged everything.

  items.update()
  player.update()
  update()
  
  img1 = font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), True, (255,255,0))
  img2 = font.render("Mode: " + player.mode, True, (255,0,0))
  try:
    img3 = font.render("Selected Item: " + player.selected_item, True, (0,255,0))
  except Exception:
    img3 = font.render("Selected Item: None", True, (0,255,0))

  screen.blit(img1, (0,0))
  screen.blit(img2, (0,24))
  screen.blit(img3, (0,48))
  
  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Alright. I will add some code.

Comment: Please read [**Minimal**, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Is all the code really needed to explain the problem? The code is way too long, it's not minimal. Your code depends on external resources such as images. Nobody can run the code without the images, so it is not reproducible.

Comment: All you have to do is add an offset to the `entity.rect2` in your `update` method as explained very well in the answer to the question [Add scrolling to a platformer in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354171/add-scrolling-to-a-platformer-in-pygame).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I know. **I have tried to implement that question into my code, but it doesn’t work. I would appreciate someone attempting to help me add this code, and am currently working on it myself.** I am very new to pygame, but that answer is **very** different from my code. I just need some help.

Comment: I don't really understand what Rytis B is saying (so maybe i'm saying the same). But you can just move all the sprite in the opposite direction of you camera. For example, I want my player to go forward -> move camera (0, -x) where x is amount forward. Then just move every sprite by (0, x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding scrolling level is very easy. You just need from `x` take away a camera x and from `y` take away a camera y, for example: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x - camerax, y - cameray))`.

**How this is working:**

Its little bit hard to answer how this works. Normaly if camerapos is always `(0, 0)` the map will not be scroling but if you move camera with player it will scroll. If you have a square at `x` 500 and you gona make camerax every second bigger by one it will move, for example: `x = 500` and `cameray = 100` screen will blit an image at `x` 400 so the image is moved, the same with the y cordinate.

**How to add a camera:**

So the most simple way is to create two ints or floats: `cx` and `cy` (camerax, cameray). But if you want something more modern you can do something like this:

```
def camera(pos):
    return pos[0] - cx, pos[1] - cy
```

**Modified code:**

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import random
import time
pygame.init()
W, Height = 800, 640

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W,Height))

SCREEN_SIZE = pygame.Rect((0,0,W,Height))
TILE_SIZE = 48

t0 = time.time()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
print("Time needed to create fonts: " + str(time.time() - t0))

vec = pygame.math.Vector2

# USER CAN MODIFY
ACC = 0.5
FRIC = -0.12
FPS = 60
cx = 0
cy = 0

def camera(pos):
    return pos[0] - cx, pos[1] - cy

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class BlueBlock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    super(BlueBlock, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.Surface((48,48))
    self.surf.fill((0,191,255))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.original_surface = self.surf
    self.hover_surface = self.original_surface.copy()
    pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_surface, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_surface.get_rect(), 6)
    self.surf = self.original_surface
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    self.hover = False
    self.mouse_pos = None
    self.count = 0
    
  def update(self):
    if player.mode == "build":
      mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
      self.surf = self.hover_surface if self.hover else self.original_surface
      if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos:
        self.count += 1
      if self.count > 10:
        self.image = pygame.Surface((48,48))
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))

class textureblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, imagefile, x, y, type):
    super(textureblock, self).__init__()
      
    self.imagefile = imagefile
    self.original_image = pygame.image.load('img.png').convert_alpha()
    self.original_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (48,48))
    self.hover_image = self.original_image.copy()
    pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    self.image = self.original_image 
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    self.hover = False
    self.mouse_pos = None
    self.count = 0
    self.type = type

  def update(self):
    if player.mode == "build":
      pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255,0,0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    elif player.mode == "destroy":
      pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255, 255,0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    self.image = self.hover_image if self.hover else self.original_image
    if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos and player.mode == "destroy":
      self.count += 1
      if self.count > 10:
        self.image = pygame.Surface((48,48))
        self.image.fill((0,191,255))

        item = Item(self.imagefile, self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.type)
        
        items.add(item)
        self.remove(blocks)
      
    else:
      self.count = 0
    self.mouse_pos = mouse_pos
  
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Player, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.Surface((40,40))
    self.surf.fill((255,0,0))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.pos = vec(0,144) # Position
    self.vel = vec(0,0) # Velocity
    self.acc = vec(0,0) # Acceleration 
    self.inventory = {} # Items can be added
    self.mode = "destroy" # Mode. Probably will be changed later
    self.selected_item = None # Selected item
  def move(self, pressed_keys):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
      self.acc.x = -ACC
      
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
      self.acc.x = ACC
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
    
    global cx, cy
    cx = self.pos.x
    cy = self.pos.y
    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0
  def update(self):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
      self.acc.x = -ACC
      
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
      self.acc.x = ACC
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
    global cx, cy
    cx = self.pos.x - 400
    cy = self.pos.y - 400
    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

    self.pos.y += self.vel.y + 0.5 * self.acc.y
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = entity.rect.top
                self.pos.y = self.rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
    if self.vel.y > 0:
      if hits: 
        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        self.vel.y = 0

  def jump(self):
    self.vel.y = -15

# Item class - Spawned when a player breaks a block.
class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, image, x, y, type):
    super(Item, self).__init__()
    self.image = pygame.image.load('img2.png').convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (24,24))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
    self.pos = vec(x, y)
    self.vel = vec(0,0)
    self.acc = vec(0,0)
    self.type = type

  def move(self):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)
    
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    hit_side = False
    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):

            # move left and hit the block on the right
            if self.vel.x < 0 and self.rect.right > entity.rect.right:
                self.rect.left = entity.rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

            # move right and hit the block on the left
            if self.vel.x > 0 and self.rect.left < entity.rect.left:
                self.rect.right = entity.rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                hit_side = True

    if hit_side:
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.acc.x = 0

  def update(self):
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)

    self.pos.y += self.vel.y + 0.5 * self.acc.y
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    for entity in blocks:
        if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = entity.rect.top
                self.pos.y = self.rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
    if self.vel.y > 0:
      if hits: 
        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        self.vel.y = 0

    # Now we check if we hit the Player
    if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
      # Attempt to check the player inventory
      if self.type not in player.inventory.keys():
        
        player.inventory[self.type] = 1
        self.kill()
      else:
        
        player.inventory.update({self.type: player.inventory.get(self.type) + 1})
        self.kill()
       
player = Player()
blueblock = BlueBlock(0,0)

running = True

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
items = pygame.sprite.Group()
miscBlocks = pygame.sprite.Group()

def drawGraph(graph, start):
  y = start
  x = 0
  for item in graph:
    if item == "O":
      spr = BlueBlock(x, y)
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      miscBlocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.surf, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "G":
      global cx
      spr = textureblock("media/Grass.jpeg", x, y, "Grass")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
      
    elif item == "S":
      spr = textureblock("media/Stone.png",x,y, "Stone")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "C":
      spr = textureblock("media/Coal.jpeg",x,y, "Coal")
      spr.rect.x = x
      spr.rect.y = y
      all_sprites.add(spr)
      blocks.add(spr)
      screen.blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
      x += 48
    elif item == "NL":
      y += 48
      x = 0
    else:
      print("Item not found: " + item)
  print("[Debug] Generation finished. Amount of blocks: " + str(len(blocks.sprites())))

def randomGen(graph):
  print("[Debug] Begin randomGen...")
  # We assume the user has not done anything with the graph, so we add the sky and grass
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('O')
  newgraph.append('NL')
  for i in range(20):
    newgraph.append('G')
  newgraph.append('NL')

  # Next begins the random ore gen
  
  for i in range(20):
    x = 0
    for i in range(20):
      # Chance of coal - 1 in 15
      iscoal = random.randint(1,15)
      
      if iscoal == 6:
        graph.append("C")
       
      else:
        graph.append("S")
      x += 48
    graph.append('NL')
  print("[Debug] randomGen finished. Block Stats: %s air blocks, %s grass blocks, %s stone blocks, %s coal blocks, and %s newlines." % (str(graph.count('O')), str(graph.count('G')), str(graph.count('S')), str(graph.count('C')), str(graph.count('NL'))))

newgraph = []
randomGen(newgraph)

all_sprites.add(player)

def update():
  screen.blit(player.surf, camera(player.rect))
  for entity in blocks:
    screen.blit(entity.image, camera(entity.rect))
  for entity in items:
    screen.blit(entity.image, camera(entity.rect))
  pygame.display.update()

drawGraph(newgraph, 0)

# Calculate the size of the level
level_width = 0
for i in newgraph:
  if i != "NL":
    level_width += 1
  elif i == "NL":
    break
level_width = level_width * TILE_SIZE

level_height = (newgraph.count("NL")-1)*TILE_SIZE

print("[Debug] Calculated level width and height: %s and %s" % (str(level_width), str(level_height)))

while running:
  screen.fill((0, 0, 255))  
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        player.jump()
      if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
      if event.key == pygame.K_e:
        if len(player.inventory) == 0:
          print("Player Inventory: Empty")
        else:
          print("Player Inventory: " + str(player.inventory).replace("{", "").replace("}","").replace(":", " x").replace("'",""))
      if event.key == pygame.K_b:
        if player.mode == "build":
          player.mode = "destroy"
        elif player.mode == "destroy":
          player.mode = "build"
        print("Changed player mode to " + player.mode)
      if event.key == pygame.K_1:
        
        player.selected_item = list(player.inventory)[0]
        print("Item: " + list(player.inventory)[0])
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      x,y = event.pos
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
      pygame.quit()
      
  miscBlocks.update()
  blocks.update()
  # blocks.draw(screen)
  
  pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  for entity in items:
    entity.move()
  # Commented out because it lagged everything.

  items.update()
  player.update()
  update()
  
  img1 = font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), True, (255,255,0))
  img2 = font.render("Mode: " + player.mode, True, (255,0,0))
  try:
    img3 = font.render("Selected Item: " + player.selected_item, True, (0,255,0))
  except Exception:
    img3 = font.render("Selected Item: None", True, (0,255,0))

  screen.blit(img1, (0,0))
  screen.blit(img2, (0,24))
  screen.blit(img3, (0,48))
  
  pygame.display.update()
```

**!IMPORTANT!**

Don't try do `cx = playerx` it will make your player go to the `x` 0, for example: `if x = 500` and `cx = 500` then the screen will blit at `x` 0. But you can do something like this `cx = playerx - 400`.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Hi, I will  add more modified code, thanks for making my answer better.

Comment: Also, if you need to test my code, the repl is here: https://replit.com/@techdude17/Python. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry, I can't edit my answer today I have some work to do, I will edit it tomorrow.

Comment: Here it is, I added modified code to my answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I did one error :( I will edit my answer again.

Comment: Hi, I have no idea why this program is not working. It is working for me. I just will add the whole code to the modiefied code.

Comment: It works! Dude, you’re a lifesaver! Accepting now!

Comment: Oh, one more thing: it seems to have broken the hover code, where it creates a yellow outline when you hover over a block? I’m not sure why, do you know?

Comment: Actually, I think I know why: the positioning is a little off, because if the mouse is, say, 2 blocks above the block, it thinks the mouse is on the block

Comment: Hi, I am very happy that my answer helped, sorry for doing that much errors in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting it! Do you know how to fx the hover issue thing?

Comment: Yes sure, I will look how to fix it.

Comment: thanks! This really helps!