# Using infinite loops in Pygame

Tags: pygame, infinite-loop

I've got a slight problem. I had some working code to simulate a game. Now I'm trying to visualise that by using pygame but it doesn't seem to be able to cope with some of the infinite loops (at least that's my assesment). When I run the code the pygame window simply stops responding. How can I get it to actually work and respond to inputs?

```
#importing stuff
import pygame
import os
import random
#setting constants and variables
WIDTH,HEIGHT=900,500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
BOARD=pygame.image.load(os.path.join("pygame2","UrImage.jpeg"))
pygame.display.set_caption("Royal Game of Ur")
BOARD=pygame.transform.scale(BOARD,(900,500))
dwwtc=True
COLOUR=(1,255,1)
FPS=5
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
CIRCLES=[]
#importing and resizing pictures
FILES=["th.jpeg","R.jpeg","redc.jpeg","OIP.jpeg","OIP (2).jpeg","OIP (3).jpeg","OIP (4).jpeg","OIP (5).jpeg","OIP (6).jpeg","OIP (7).jpeg","OIP (8).jpeg","OIP (9).jpeg","OIP (10).jpeg","OIP (11).jpeg"]
for index,File in enumerate(FILES):
    Kreis=pygame.image.load(os.path.join("pygame2",File))
    CIRCLES.append(Kreis)
for index,Circle in enumerate(CIRCLES):
    CIRCLES[index]=pygame.transform.scale(Circle,(20,20))
#setting the coordinates corresponding to fields of the board
movement=[(10,10),(20,20),(30,30),(40,40),(50,50),(60,60),(70,70)]
#main game loop
while dwwtc:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            dwwtc=False
    WIN.fill(COLOUR)
    WIN.blit(BOARD,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
#positions of the figurines
    positions={0:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],1:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
#setting variables which need to be updated
    endofgame=0
    figurines_before_end=0
    go_to_next_player=0
    rosettelist=[4,8]
    #actual game
    while True:
        for index,(player,value) in enumerate(positions.items()):
            while True:
#set change
                #start=pygame.key.get_pressed
                #if start==pygame.key.get_pressed():
                a=random.randint(0,1)
                b=random.randint(0,1)
                c=random.randint(0,1)
                d=random.randint(0,1)
                change=a+b+c+d
                print(change)
#state opposing player
                if index==0:
                    opponent=1
                elif index==1:
                    opponent=0
#checking pressed key and corresponding figurine
                while True:
                    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if True in key:
                        if key[pygame.K_0]:
                            figurine=0
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_1]:
                            figurine=1
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_2]:
                            figurine=2
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_3]:
                            figurine=3
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_4]:
                            figurine=4
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_5]:
                            figurine=5
                            break
                        elif key[pygame.K_6]:
                            figurine=6
                            break
#checking conditions for figurine movement
                        if 0 <= figurine <= 6:
                            print("a")
                            if positions[index][figurine] <=14:
                                print("b")
                                if positions[index][figurine]+change <16:
                                    print("c")
# if positions[index][figurine]+change not in positions[index] and positions[index][figurine]<15:
                                        print("d")
                                        break
                                    elif positions[index][figurine]+change==15:
                                        print("z")
                                        break
                                    elif change==0:
                                        print("j")
                                        break
                                    elif positions[index][figurine]+change==7 and 7 in positions[opponent]:
                                        print("y")
                                        continue
#checking if it's possible to add the change without the figurine going further than the end field
                                else:
                                    for v in positions[index]:
                                        if v+change<16:
                                            figurines_before_end=1
                                            break
                                        else:
                                            figurines_before_end=2
                                if figurines_before_end==2:
                                    change=0
                                    break    
#If all conditions have been met, the change is added to the position
                        positions[index][figurine]+=change
#Show the player's circle at its new position
                        if opponent==0:
                            WIN.blit(CIRCLES[figurine],(movement[positions[index][figurine]]))
                        elif opponent==1:
                            WIN.blit(CIRCLES[figurine*2],(movement[positions[index][figurine]]))
                        pygame.display.update()
                        print(positions)
#If the figurine of the opponent is in the new position, they're sent back to the start
                        if positions[index][figurine] in positions[opponent] and 5<= positions[index][figurine] <=12:
                            for indexchen,werte in enumerate(positions[opponent]):
                                
                                if werte==positions[index][figurine]:
                                    positions[opponent][indexchen]=0
                                    if opponent==1:
                                        WIN.blit(CIRCLES[index],(movement[0]))
                                    elif opponent==0:
                                        WIN.blit(CIRCLES[index*2],(movement[0]))
                                    break
                                pygame.display.update()
                        print(positions)
#Check if player is entitled to a second go
                        if positions[index][figurine] not in rosettelist:
                            go_to_next_player=1
                            break
                if go_to_next_player==1:
                    break
#Check if all figurines have reached the end and react appropriately
            if all(value>14 for value in positions[index]):
                endofgame=1
                break
        if endofgame==1:
            break
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I've written a few smaller programs, including one which could react to keyboard inputs. I then put this into an infinite loop and the pygame window stopped responding. Since I've got several infinite loops in my actual code, I guessed that they're the problem.

Comment: You should only have one infinite loop, `while dwwtc:`  One iteration of this loop corresponds to one frame of your game. If you block this loop, your game will not function. Nesting loops will not achieve the results you are after.  Your game loop should contain the following components: event handling → update state → draw new state → update display. Take a look at some [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357169/2280890). Or have a look at an [openbook](https://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html) on this subject.